# Jenkins slave agent service do not work since java update (which removed medium security level)

Tags: jenkins

**Situation:**
Yesterday morning, all of our Slaves had problems (because thanks to Java, which removed the medium security level, the Jenkins slave agent could not be launched anymore). Java then started blocking all `Jenkins slave agent.jlnp`, we had to add on every slave an exception for our jenkins server, so the slave application can be launched. This was annoying but now they work. *(was there an easier solution?)*

Few slaves had Jenkins installed as a service (to be launched automatically on startup). However, since yesterday, they do not launch anymore, and we cannot find why. It probably has to do with the security from Java.

Someone has any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You need to update jenkins reference to Java. It is in file C:\Jenkins\jenkins-slave.xml (or whereever is your Jenkins folder). When you updated Java Jenkins no longer knows where to find new version

Mine looks something like this.

```
<executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe</executable>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is there a way to automate this. I regularly have to change java path on all slaves...

Answer (score 1):

I made it works with the following steps:

1-) Uninstalling service
2-) Reboot
3-) Installing service
4-) Reboot